# Do I need to use capacitors when using an L7805CV voltage regulator?

Tags: arduino

I am building a small water pump (5 V) controlled by an Arduino, and I want to reduce voltage from 9 V to 5 V.

Do I need to use capacitors when using an L7805CV voltage regulator?

[image]

Comment: Using a regulator to power a motor is needless complication... why not use a 5V power supply? (aka cellphone charger) these are cheap...

Comment: Hello yuria,

If you do not have a 5V supply why not run the motor at 9V with a lower duty PWM signal?  Why does the motor need to run at 5V?

Comment: Why is this not a duplicate? It sounds like a question that has been asked at least 100 times before. Is there anything special about "CV"?

Comment: [An explanation for the requirement for an input capacitor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/217088).

Answer (score 15):

From [the L7805CV's datasheet](https://datasheet.octopart.com/L7805CV-STMicroelectronics-datasheet-7264666.pdf):

[image]

So while you might get away without the capacitor, you're better off with it, it likely won't hurt.

Comment: Add on: motors are noisy loads. Having some capacitance would help filter some of the noise.

Comment: In other words, if you have to ask, follow the datasheet?

Comment: it probably won't but it might damage surrounding components. And motor coils are inductors - if there are also capacitors in circuit, you could be unlucky and have weird resonant effects doing odd things. Basically, unwanted oscillation (even marginal) is *always* bad news and you try to avoid it.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, or you risk that the regulator will oscillate (which you won't see without a scope). This can cause all kinds of problems. You typically want an electrolytic capacitor of about 10 µF and a ceramic capacitor of about 0.1 µF in parallel on both input and output, as close to the regulator as possible - that's four capacitors.

You also probably want some protection diodes around the regulator to prevent reverse voltages damaging it. Consult the device datasheet for examples and recommendations.

Comment: how can the oscillation hurt the motor?

Answer (score -3):

Yes, since you're using a 9 V adapter to power up the circuit, I would say it's good to have a capacitor because you won't risk fluctuations in the output voltage. It's better to have it to make it work under optimal conditions.

Comment: This answer doesn't add anything new or a new angle to previous answers, and is less specific than other answers given so far.